# Why HTTPSConnectionPool doesn't work when PoolManager does?

Tags: python, urllib3

I have tested a 'POST' request with both PoolManager and HTTPSConnectionPool. The first one works, the other throw me a :

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://some.url.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /some-api (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>:
[Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Here's my code for PoolManager:

```
import urllib3

HOST = 'https://some.url.com'
PORT = 443
PATH = '/some-api'
xml_request = '<some xml tree/>'

manager = urllib3.PoolManager()
res = manager.request('POST', HOST+PATH, {'req':xml_request})
```

and for HTTPSConnectonPool:

```
manager = urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool(HOST, port=PORT)
res = manager.request('POST', PATH, {'req':xml_request})
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see this as a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`https://some.url.com` is not a hostname or IP address, it's a URL. So you're feeding the wrong information to `HTTPSConnectionPool`.

Furthermore, `PoolManager` and `HTTPSConnectionPool` are not at the same abstraction level. `PoolManager` manages `ConnectionPool` instances for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I know those are different, and that's why I tried HTTPSConnectionPool first (cause I don't have to manage many pools).

Comment: While this is a good answer and it is safe to use PoolManager in this instance with no downsides, @Yann's original question should function properly if we change the `HOST` to `some.url.com` (without the `https://`).

Comment: @shazow this is what I implied by my first sentence