# Use openssl, requests and wincertstore to Get Client Certificates

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, client-certificates, pyopenssl

I have code to walk through my `wincertstore` and find a certificate by name and/or thumbprint.

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    for storename in ["MY"]:  # "ROOT", "CA",
        with wincertstore.CertSystemStore(storename) as store:
            for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.CLIENT_AUTH):
                print(cert.get_name())
                print(cert.cert_type)
                print(cert.enhanced_keyusage_names())
                # pem = cert.get_pem()
                # encodedDer = ''.join(pem.split("\n")[1:-2])
                # cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(encodedDer)
                cert_pem = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert.get_encoded())
                cert_details = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(
                    cert_pem.encode('utf-8'), default_backend()
                )
                serial_number = hex(cert_details.serial_number).replace("0x", "")
                cert_details.fingerprint
                if cert.get_name().lower() == find_name.lower():
                    pem_data = cert.get_pem()
                    break
if pem_data:
   f = open('./mycert.pem', 'w')
   f.write(pem_data)
   f.close()
   del f

import requests 
resp = requests.get(<some url>, cert='./mycert.pem')
```

This gives an SSL Error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*****.e***.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gis/sharing/rest/portals/self/servers?f=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3932)')))
```

So what else do I need to pull from the window's certificate store to pass the client certificate?

Comment: Please show us a minimal example.

Comment: The code above is an example that works.  I can't share a PKI certificate.

Comment: Is 'mycert.pem' both private key and cert?

Comment: @NizamMohamed I believe you can extract the certificate from the store with both key/cert.  Using the pythonnet library I can get the certificate, but it seems really odd that there is no package to work with windows cert stores really.

Comment: The private key to your local certificate must be unencrypted. Currently, Requests does not support using encrypted keys.

Comment: You must pass if cert and key are separate, as  `cert=(<cert>, <private key>)`

Comment: `wincertstore` provides an interface to access Windows’ CA and CRL certificates. And  you're talking about **client** certs!

Comment: `wincertstore` is deprecated. Since Python 2.7.9 `ssl.create_default_context()` automatically loads certificates from Windows’ cert store.

Comment: ok so ssl.create_default_context() is better, but it's still the same issue. You can parse the wincert store items into cert/ private keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be running into a bug on urllib3 Try updating it to the latest version:

https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#changes

Comment: Can you explain what you are pointing out a bit more?

Comment: Hey JabberJabber, 
Sorry been AFK for a bit. When I researched the error I found that link I shared. It talks about urllib3 is being deprecated. 

I just took a fresh look and I actually think you are feeding the wrong information from your pem_data variable. Here is another overflow that talks about it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160244/why-httpsconnectionpool-doesnt-work-when-poolmanager-does 
Can you confirm pem_data is a hostname or IP and not a URL of some sort? Thanks